# Calling Template function from class

Tags: c++

I now have a fixed code

```
template<class _Fn, class... _Args>
void Profiling::GetProfile(_Fn&& _Fx, _Args&&... _Ax)
{
    StartTime = clock();
    function<void()> f = bind(_Decay_copy(forward<_Fn>(_Fx)), _Decay_copy(forward<_Args>(_Ax))...);
    f();
    EndTime = clock();

}
```

But can not call from main using

```
Profiling VarTest;
VarTest.GetProfile(Test, 1, 5);
```

where Test is a function that takes two integers

```
void Test(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << a + b;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with "can not call" ?

Comment: Because `Test` isn't `void()`.

Comment: Just call it directly.. etc `callable(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

Comment: By not call i mean "Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Profiling::GetProfile<void (__cdecl&)(int,int),int,int>(void (__cdecl&)(int,int),int &&,int &&)" (??$GetProfile@A6AXHH@ZHH@Profiling@@QAEXA6AXHH@Z$$QAH1@Z) referenced in function _main 
"

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems, if you use template for a function parameter this needs to be in the header file, rather than the source file.